# bar line mpandroid chart

Tags: android, android-layout, charts, mpandroidchart

I have a chart and use mpandroidchart
the shape is as shown below
[image]

how can my line be neat and not too sideways?

Comment: Have you tried sample app ?

Comment: already brother

Comment: Sample project is working fine.

Comment: sample project combine chart for group bar not 1 bar chart :(

Comment: In the sample, there is combined chart (bar and linechart)

Comment: Which version of library are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version above 3 then you need to modify your xAxis as follows and last two lines of code will solve your issue:

```
 // xAxis customization
    XAxis xAxis = combinedChart.getXAxis();

    // Following code have no effect but you can change it if required
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

    //xAxis.setXOffset(2);

    // Setting maximum limit of xAxis
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(barData().getEntryCount());

    // Setting position of xAxis
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED); 

    // This is used to fix bar width of first bar
    **xAxis.setSpaceMin(barData().getBarWidth() / 2f);
    xAxis.setSpaceMax(barData().getBarWidth() / 2f);**
```

Comment: Do let me know if further assistance is required. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but its worked for me.

This error comes from X Axis starting point.
Set starting point as 1.

```
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(1); // or xAxis.setAxisMinimum(2);
```